# How to document that certain test cases intentionally fail?

Tags: java, testing, junit, documentation

I am currently investigating a JPA issue we have. I came up with two possible solutions in my mind for that problem. I wrote a set of unit tests that show how each solution would solve the problem. During testing each solution I discovered that one won't work.

Now I would like to document **why** that specific solution won't do the job. I could rewrite the unit tests, that I currently have, to expect exceptions. However the exceptions are only symptoms of the underlying problem of that solution. So I created a new unit test that clearly shows the point, where that solution is in conflict with the JPA specification. However I would like to keep those other failing tests as a documentation of the symptoms that may arise with such a solution. So I could disable them and put javadoc on them saying that they are disabled because of that specific test case.

Note that I don't want to have a failing test case. Otherwise I also could use [assumes](https://github.com/junit-team/junit.contrib/tree/master/assumes).

Is there any other way how I can document that a number of tests don't need to be executed, because they would fail due to another test documenting the real problem being successful?

I'm restricted to use junit for my solution.

**EDIT:**
Concerning comments and answers so far, I would prefer the Categories, because the test would still be executable without any change, if someone wishes them to be executed. What I'm still concerned with is a stronger association of the tests that represent symptoms of the problems with the real cause. That would currently just be a javadoc link from a symptom test to the real cause test.

Comment: Can't you use [Categories](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.html) and put those tests in a "fail-on-purpose" category that is not run in your normal unit testing session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [@Ignore](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Ignore.java), with a message:

```
@Test
@Ignore("This fails because of a problem with the specification")
public void testWhichFails() {
}
```

This test won't be run, and you'll know why as well.

Comment: I finally choose that, because it is the simpletest and the test don't need to run every time. They are only important in my case when the JPA provider or its version changes. I also pointed to the test that shows the real problem from within the javadoc of the ignored tests.